# Is it possible to reset a jQuery deferred object state?

Tags: jquery-deferred

Is it possible to reset a resolved jQuery object to an 'unresolved' state and kick off it's initialization and callbacks all over again?

The specific thing I'm doing is that I have a jQuery deferred wrapper over the local file system api. From there I build up higher level deferreds for the things I care about:

```
var getFs = defFs.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024)
              .pipe (bytes) -> defFs.requestFs(PERSISTENT, bytes)

var getCacheContents = getFs.pipe (fileSystem) -> 
      defFs.getDirectory('Cache', fileSystem.root).pipe (dir) ->
          defFs.readEntries(dir)
```

Now most of the time, when I call getCacheContents I don't mind the memo-ized values being returned, in fact I prefer it. But, on the occasion when I want to write to the cache I really would like the ability to reset that pipe and have it re-select and rescan the cache next time its accessed.

I could cobble something together from $.Callbacks but a deferred-based solution would really be ideal.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, not without some hack. Deferreds are resolved or rejected and that's that - any callbacks attached after fire (or don't, depending on whether it's a success/failure callback) immediately. Any reason (sorry if I missed this from your question) why you specifically need the same deferred rather than a new one?

Comment: @Utkanos - Other bits of code might already hold a reference to that deferred. (which in my case is just "when you get the cache directory contents") they don't care whether it takes a while to return the results or if they return a value immediately they DO however expect that value to be current and correct

Comment: related: [One time event handling using promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23116562/1048572)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. A `Promise` is by [definition](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) a thing that resolves only once - from `unresolved` to `fulfilled` OR to `rejected`. You will not be able to do this with jQuery's `Deferred`s.

What you are actually searching for are [Signals](http://13thparallel.com/archive/sig-slots/). They are to be fired more than once, but provide a similiar interface. There are some implementations around, you might ceck out [`js-signals`](http://millermedeiros.github.com/js-signals/) or [`wire.js`](https://github.com/cujojs/wire#readme).

Comment: Upon reviewing those links I don't think that's what I want, wire.js seems like complete overkill for most js projects I've been involved with, and js-signlas seems identical to the built in jQuery.Callbacks. What I want is something with the memoization capabilities and interface of a promise but which I can reset. I suppose I could always include a lazy loading-style lock, it just makes constructing my dsl a little less intention revealing

Comment: While a Promise must be understandably inmutable, why should it not be possible to reset the state on the Deferred object itself? Not trolling, just asking if there's any architectural / pattern reason.

Comment: Promise and Deferred are linked, as soon as the Deferred's state changes the [Promise's] handlers are fired. You can't really reset it and create new promises from it, if that's what you mean. I'd say the architecture pattern is like "the promise is a [save] view on the deferred without the trigger methods"

Comment: Right, you'll have to recreate the Promise handler ties, but since you can only resolve once it doesn't really matter after all as you can't fire twice? I found myself liberally rerequesting Promises whenever I reenter a view and this way if the Deferred has been reset I get the data from the new Promise. What's the motivation for maintaining the original?

Comment: Yes, you can fire it only once. But the benefit of promises is that you can add multiple callbacks (at any time), and they will memorize the [potentially future] value they represent.

Comment: jQuery supports signals in the event of custom events (https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)

Comment: @pianomansam Events are not signals, which have a value at any time instead of "occurring" at specific times. Another term for signals is "observable".

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I could find is to reset the `$.Deferred` object and return new Promise from that one. It works together with some internal API dirty checking (if something gets edited / deleted), but would be more performant to just reset the existing `$.Deferred` and let it re-resolve on the next Promise request.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a possible solution is:

```
$.myDeferredList = [];
$.createRestorableDeferred = function(a,b) {
    // JUST BY SIMPLE $.when().then();
    $.myDeferredList[a] = {
        deferred: $.Deferred()
        , then: b
        ,restore : function() {
            $.myDeferredList['myReady'].deferred = $.Deferred();
            $.when($.myDeferredList['myReady'].deferred).then($.myDeferredList['myReady'].then);
        }
        ,resolve : function() {
            $.myDeferredList['myReady'].deferred.resolve();
        }
    }
    $.when($.myDeferredList['myReady'].deferred).then($.myDeferredList['myReady'].then);
    window[a] = $.myDeferredList['myReady'];
}

 var counter = 0;
 $.createRestorableDeferred('myReady', function () {
     console.log('>> myReady WHEN called',++counter);
     $.myDeferredList['myReady'].restore();

 });

// RESOLVING ways

$.myDeferredList['myReady'].deferred.resolve();
$.myDeferredList.myReady.deferred.resolve();
myReady.resolve();
```

Results in console:

```
 >> myReady WHEN called 1

 >> myReady WHEN called 2

 >> myReady WHEN called 3
```

Comment: Sure but first, I don't think there's any benefit for having a deferred list, you could simply return the object (also no need to implicitly override things in the global namespace with `window[a]` - can you imagine if someone named a deferred `"location"`?) More importantly, this actually doesn't reset the deferred, it simply creates a container that you can add a new deferred to, but any perviously attached `then` continuations will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery [custom event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) placed on a DOM element such as `<body>` is much more suited for this than Deferred.