# Cannot remove the State of Defer Object

Tags: jquery

```
 var defer8 = $.Deferred();
    function get_outlet_data()
    {
        db.transaction(populateDBOutlet);
        retrieve_Data_outlet(localStorage.username);
     defer8.resolve();
    }


$.when(defer8).then(function() {
 });
```

Here i used defer object to wait until the function get_outlet_data run.But i need to remove the state of defer8 inside the **When function**

Comment: what you mean by cannot remove the state... what are you trying to do in the `when`

Comment: You cannot using deferred, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762619/is-it-possible-to-reset-a-jquery-deferred-object-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var get_outlet_data = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    db.transaction(populateDBOutlet);
    retrieve_Data_outlet(localStorage.username);
    deferred.resolve(); // Note: the lines above are probably asynchronous, so you want to resolve the promise when they are done
    return deferred.promise();
};

$.when(get_outlet_data()).then(function () {
    // No need to remove the state, because the deferred will be re-created on a second call
});
```

What I did was move the deferred object inside the function, so it is re-created every time you call the function. Therefore there should be no need to 'reset the state' (which I think is not possible anyway)

Edit: Just so you know, there's an error in your code: $.when does not accept a deferred object, it accepts a promise. So the correct way to use it is $.when(deferred.promise(), ...) and not $.when(deferred, ...)

Comment: $.when works with deferred object. Anyway, promise interface is part of the deferred object. That's said, your answer is the only one i can think of to fit in some way OP issue (if i understand his question). But still, with that, OP cannot keep reference on a deferred object